Did Ellen White say that the book of Hebrew was written by Paul?
Did Ellen White say that the book of Hebrews was written by Paul? According to the Seventh-day Adventist Commentary, the book of Hebrews has many differences compared to Paul's other writings.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

I am not familiar personally with EG Whites view on the authorship of Hebrews, however, i do know that in a general sense there is evidence to support the Epistle as being attributed either directly or indirectly to the apostle Paul.
We can probably rest this claim to a large extent on the KJV bible as the superscription has the following title... "The Epistle of Paul the Apostle to the Hebrews" even though this was almost certainly a later edit to the original KJV title.
Clement of Alexandria in the late 100's early 200's concluded that Paul wrote it.
Origen was a bit ambiguous but seemingly thought it may have been written by the apostle Paul.

tentatively accepted Pauline origin of the thought in the text and the
the thoughts are
those of the apostle, but the diction and phraseology are those of
some one who remembered the apostolic teachings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Epistle_to_the_Hebrews

Eusebius states the following about authorship:

If I gave my opinion, I should say that the thoughts are those of the
apostle, but the diction and phraseology are those of someone who
remembered the apostolic teachings and wrote down at his leisure what
had been said by his teacher. Therefore if any church holds that this
epistle is by Paul, let it be commended for this. For not without
reason have the ancients handed it down as Paul’s. But who wrote the
episde, in truth, God knows. The statement of some who have gone
before us is that Clement, bishop of Romans, wrote the epistle, and of
others that Luke, the author of the Gospel and the Acts, wrote it. But
let this suffice on these matters (Eusebius, Ecclesiastical History,
6:25)

A good article about this is by Prof Felix Cortez and published through Andrews University is
ON THE AUTHORSHIP OF HEBREWS: THE CASE FOR PAUL
Another source states the following about EG Whites view of authorship...

There is no record of White discussing the issue of authorship of the
Letter to the Hebrews. She refers to Paul in relationship to Hebrews
only when introducing a quotation from or an allusion to the letter.
This practice was likely because Hebrews appeared in her Bible (KJV)
under the title “The Epistle of Paul the Apostle to the Hebrews.”
However, once she began to reference the letter this way, it appears
that it was impossible for Adventists to see this other than an
implied endorsement of Paul’s authorship of the letter.

https://spectrummagazine.org/views/authorship-hebrews-reviewing-cortezs-case-part-1/
An interesting point to note about the New Testament, most if not all of its books are authored by apostles or authors who were contemporaries to the apostles (quite likely under direction from an apostle). I think this is why we attribute Hebrews to Paul or one of his followers.
My view is that Paul probably instructed the person who wrote Hebrews and a likely individual is Apollos. So even if not directly, indirectly Paul is a good candidate especially given the KJV bible superscription. I also have to argue that given Hebrews was eventually accepted into the Bible canon as a writing of a significant Christian church founder (such as an apostle or contemporary instructed by an apostle) its highly likely someone with a gospel message very similar to the Apostle Pauls preaching clearly had input into its writing. I do not think it would be heresy to claim Paul as its author...it is a truly wonderful book and goes hand in hand with the book of Romans (which Paul obviously did write). Wouldnt it be fabulous if we found evidence that it was authored by a number of the apostles as a collective (given it appears Lukes name comes up in discussion among scholars about this Epistle)

Some translations include a note at the end that states: "Written to the Hebrews from Italy by Timothy." Now, whether that was incorrectly added later or Timothy was the author's amanuensis may be debatable, but I'll note that Timothy apparently helped Paul write several other epistles.
